# unable to get the model attribute comparison result

Tags: backbone.js

In my backbone collection, this is the model data i have:

```
var student = [
        {name:"student0",scored:75},
        {name:"student1",scored:49},
        {name:"student2",scored:25}
    ]
```

from the model data(collection), i am trying to get the 'scored' attribute more than 60... 
To do this i use this method,

on click i am calling a method called 'showHighScore',

```
getHighSocre:function(){
        return _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
            return parseInt(item.get('scored')) > 60
        })
    },
    showHighScore:function(){
        var highscore = this.getHighSocre();
        console.log(highscore);//i am getting the result as undifined
    }
```

when the 'showHighScore' called, i am looping and returning the values, but the console giving me a result as 'undefined'.. is this the way is wrong.. or what is the correct way to get the model collections which has the attribute 'scored' more than 60...

any one help me.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var student = [
        {name:"student0",scored:75},
        {name:"student1",scored:49},
        {name:"student2",scored:25}
    ];

var test = _.filter(student, function(item){ return item.scored > 60 });

console.log(test);
```

[DEMO && CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/XDEmA/)

For getting the json, you should use

```
var students = this.collection.toJSON();
```

Then return a new collection from the method, or refresh the current collection.